# Регулярные выражения: заменить строку на html эквивалент

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Привет всем. Уже неплохо ориентируюсь в регулярке, но опять появилась проблема.

Пользователь при отправке комментария может вставить картинку, которая в форме отправки имеет вид

```
[img:http://path_to_image]
```

На сервере эта строка заменяется на html-эквивалент:

```
$postcomment =  preg_replace("/\[img:(.*?)\]/s" ,"<img src='$1' />", $postcomment);
```

Увы, если в первоначальной строке в адресе **http://path_to_image** будет присутствовать перевод строки - пользователя (и меня) будет ждать облом.

Как заменить все переводы строк и пробелы с помощью регулярки? У меня ничего не получается.

Comment: У меня не строка, у меня текст, который содержит элементы [img:http://path_to_image]. Их может быть сколько угодно. Нужно регулярное выражение.

Comment: @ua6xh, уверены, что картинка после такой замены отобразится?

Comment: Пользователь при вводе адреса картинки в поле textarea может случайно нажать лишний "ентер" - пост-данные так и отправятся с этим ентером. url-адрес будет неверным. Нужно избавиться от лишних переводов строк!

Comment: Обработка в цикле - это давно забытое старое...

Comment: @ua6xh, это подход из серии -- "гильотина - лучшее средство от головной боли".

Вообще-то проблему ввода допустимых символов лучше решать на стороне клиента.

Comment: @avp - не прав, буду ждать элегантного и красивого решения от более опытных программистов.

Comment: @avp, дааа, действительно сложный вопрос. Конечно, я могу сделать javascript'ом. Однако, уже действительно интересно **как все-таки заменить определенные символы в конкретных подстроках текста**?

Comment: @Deus, думаю стандартную функцию [trim](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php) вполне можно приспособить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно как-нибудь так:

```
function delete_endl($matches)
{
    $matches[0] = str_replace("\n","",$matches[0]);
    return preg_replace("/\[img:(.*?)\]/s" ,"<img src='$1' />", $matches[0]);;
}
$postcomment = preg_replace_callback("/\[img:(.*?)\]/s", "delete_endl", $postcomment);
```

Comment: отлично! спасибо! У меня была мысль про коллбэк, но до конца не мог додумать!!!!!!

Comment: @avp, если невозможно использовать даже str_replace, то что уже говорить о trim, функция, которая убирает пробелы **только в начале и конце строки**. А у меня в середине подстрок с img может быть сколь угодно много пробелов и переводов строк! Ответ уже дан. И это отлично.

Comment: @Deus, а что Вы думаете делать с нормальными файлами с **пробелами внутри имени**?

Естественно, строку перед trim надо разбирать, применить trim именно к имени файла (предполагаем, что в начале и конце пробелов не должно быть), а потом собирать. Имя же, вставляемое после `src=` видимо надо заключать в кавычки.

Comment: @avp, ну вы же видели правильный ответ! Какой разбор строки?? Имя и так в кавычках! Присмотритесь. 
    "<img src='$1' />"

Comment: Правда нужны ковычки, а не апострафы

Comment: @MDJHD, ничего не нужно. Сайт уже 3 часа как нормально  работает! я не знаю, разве w3c настаивает именно на апострофах в html? Кавычки придется экранировать, лишняя работа

Comment: Не буду утверждать насчет всех стандартов w3c, но XHTML требует ковычки 100%

Answer (score 0):

Перед разбором регуляркой сделайте:

```
$postcomment = str_replace("\n", "", $postcomment);
```

.

Comment: @terantul, не тут то было! Я и так заменяю переводы строк на <br /> для эстетичного отображения. А до такой замены, мне нужно удалить переводы строк именно в подстроках [img:url]

Comment: @MDJHD, вы настоятельно рекомендуете использовать экранированные кавычки ВСЕГДА или это совет? Не знаю, сейчас !DOCTYPE html, он видимо включает в себя XHTML. На моих проектах это вообще никак не отражается.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте модификатор /m (PCRE_MULTILINE)

```
$postcomment =  preg_replace("/\[img:(.*?)\]/m" ,"<img src='$1' />", $postcomment);
```